# React Native Email App Launch Crashes in Production Build

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to be able to launch the main email app on a user's device (iOS& Android) from a react-native app. so i use the code below:

```js
import { Linking, Alert, ToastAndroid } from "react-native";
<TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.supportCard}
              onPress={() => { handleMailPress(mail)}}
            > 
...
            </TouchableOpacity>
export const handleMailPress = async (mailAddress) => {
  const url = `mailto:${mailAddress}`;
  const canOpen = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
  if (canOpen) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
  } else {
    Alert.alert("Erreur", "Error.");
  }
};
```

the code is working perfectly on expo simulator, but when i build the .apk file it does not!

i tried to fix this but no luck so far.

Comment: Do you have access to a stack trace or some logs which could explain the source of the crash?

Comment: No i don't how it, Is there a specific code or library I need to use to add logging functionality to my app?

Comment: In Android Studio, there is a tool called Logcat to view and filter logs from any device connected to your computer. When an app crashes, it is usually possible to learn more by looking at the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give the app permission to use the schema?

From the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)

> The Promise will reject on Android if it was impossible to check if the URL can be opened or when targetting Android 11 (SDK 30) if you didn't specify the relevant intent queries in AndroidManifest.xml. Similarly on iOS, the promise will reject if you didn't add the specific scheme in the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key inside Info.plist.

> When targeting Android 11 (SDK 30) you must specify the intents for the schemes you want to handle in AndroidManifest.xml. A list of common intents can be found here.

> For example to handle https schemes the following needs to be added to your manifest:

```xml
<manifest ...>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

So I guess you want to modify `app.json`

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "SENDTO",
          "data": {
            "scheme": "mailto"
          },
          "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Such that Expo generates this in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```